# Using a Eigen type inside boost graph

Tags: c++, eigen, boost-graph

I've got some Eigen alignment issues when adding a vertex to the following graph:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

struct Vertex
{
   EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
   Eigen::Affine3d T; // Here is the Fixed-size vectorizable Eigen object
};


struct aligned_listS { };

namespace boost 
{
  template <class ValueType>
  struct container_gen<aligned_listS, ValueType> 
  {
    typedef std::list<ValueType, Eigen::aligned_allocator<ValueType> > type;
  };
}

typedef boost::adjacency_list< boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex> MyGraph;

int main(int, char*[])
{
   Vertex v;

   MyGraph g;
   boost::add_vertex(v, g);

   return 0;
}
```

At run time,I have the following error message:

```
 /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:56: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double, int Size = 16, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
```

It seems that either the aligned_listS template argument is not set at the good place or my aligned allocator is not well defined. 
So I'm looking for some hints on how making this aligned allocator works properly.

Here is the full gdb backtrace if it can help:

```
#0  0xb7fdf1b2 in _dl_sysinfo_int80 () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#1  0xb7d401df in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0xb7d43825 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
#3  0xb7d39085 in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0xb7e76c38 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", 
    assertion=0x804b324 "(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && \"this assertion is explained here: \" \"http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html\" \" **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****\"", file=0x804b2ec "/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h", 
    line=56, 
    function=0x804b5e0 "Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double, int Size = 16, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]") at assert.c:94
#4  0xb7d39137 in __GI___assert_fail (
    assertion=0x804b324 "(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && \"this assertion is explained here: \" \"http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html\" \" **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****\"", file=0x804b2ec "/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h", 
    line=56, 
    function=0x804b5e0 "Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = double, int Size = 16, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]") at assert.c:103
#5  0x08049f1c in Eigen::internal::plain_array<double, 16, 0, 16>::plain_array() ()
#6  0x080499f1 in Eigen::DenseStorage<double, 16, 4, 4, 0>::DenseStorage() ()
#7  0x0804935a in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4> >::PlainObjectBase() ()
#8  0x08048ec7 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4>::Matrix() ()
#9  0x08049d71 in Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0>::Transform(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&) ()
#10 0x080496c0 in Vertex::Vertex(Vertex const&) ()
#11 0x080496e9 in boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config::seq_stored_vertex::seq_stored_vertex(Vertex const&) ()
#12 0x080491cc in boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config::stored_vertex::stored_vertex(Vertex const&) ()
#13 0x08048df3 in boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config::vertex_descriptor boost::add_vertex<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config, boost::directed_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config> >(boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config::vertex_property_type const&, boost::adj_list_impl<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config, boost::directed_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, aligned_listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, aligned_listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, Vertex, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config> >&) ()
#14 0x080489be in main ()
```

Comment: I don't get this error. What compiler version and Eigen version are you using?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and using g++ (4.6.3), with Eigen 3.1.3 and boost 1.52.0. To compile, I used the command "g++ graph.cpp -I/usr/local/include/eigen3", and no other flags.

Comment: EDIT: class Vertex -> struct Vertex, as EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW must be public.

Answer (score 2):

A way to go around is to have the following graph definition :

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list< boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::shared_ptr<Vertex> > MyGraph;
```

And in this case, this code does not generate the assert.

```
   boost::shared_ptr<Vertex> ptr(new Vertex(v));
   boost::add_vertex(ptr, g);
```

In this case, the Eigen macro seems to make the job. However, I still don't understand why the first code is not running. Using a pointer is more a patch than the solution...